# WebGL website looks fine on PC, but looks weird on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, webgl, shader

So I made a WebGL website and it can be accessed here:
https://jameswebsite.azurewebsites.net/

It looks fine(or as expected) on the PC, but on mobile devices it looks funny. Looks like the texture mapping might be off (maybe texture clipping is the problem) but also there doesn't appear to be any shading occuring.

Here is the screenshot from the PC:

PC Image
[image: ![PC Image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7SDj.png)

Here is the screenshot from the Mobile Device:

Mobile Image
[image: Mobile Image]

I have turned off the textures and still have this problem. This leads me to believe the problem could be in my shaders. Here are my shaders:

```
<script id="per-fragment-lighting-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;
varying vec4 vPosition;

uniform float uMaterialShininess;

uniform bool uShowSpecularHighlights;
uniform bool uUseLighting;
uniform bool uUseTextures;

uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;

uniform vec3 uPointLightingLocation;
uniform vec3 uPointLightingSpecularColor;
uniform vec3 uPointLightingDiffuseColor;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;


void main(void) {
    vec3 lightWeighting;
    if (!uUseLighting) {
        lightWeighting = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    } else {
        vec3 lightDirection = normalize(uPointLightingLocation - vPosition.xyz);
        vec3 normal = normalize(vTransformedNormal);

        float specularLightWeighting = 0.0;
        if (uShowSpecularHighlights) {
            vec3 eyeDirection = normalize(-vPosition.xyz);
            vec3 reflectionDirection = reflect(-lightDirection, normal);

            specularLightWeighting = pow(max(dot(reflectionDirection, eyeDirection), 0.0), uMaterialShininess);
        }

        float diffuseLightWeighting = max(dot(normal, lightDirection), 0.0);
        lightWeighting = uAmbientColor
            + uPointLightingSpecularColor * specularLightWeighting
            + uPointLightingDiffuseColor * diffuseLightWeighting;
    }

    vec4 fragmentColor;
    if (uUseTextures) {
        fragmentColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
    } else {
        fragmentColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(fragmentColor.rgb * lightWeighting, fragmentColor.a);
}
```

```
<script id="per-fragment-lighting-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;
varying vec4 vPosition;


void main(void) {
    vPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * vPosition;
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    vTransformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You may need to explicity set your `gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T` settings to `gl.GL_REPEAT` on your texture object(s)

Comment: change `mediump` to `highp` in your shaders and see what that does

Comment: @gman that worked! Thanks a bunch! I never would have found that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @gman:

> change mediump to highp in your shaders and see what that does

This actually worked!! Thanks @gman!

Comment: so just to clarify, in 2011 when WebGL came out lots of phones did not support `highp`. On most modern phones in 2018 phones support both `mediump` and `highp` but `highp` is slower so you need to decide when you use `highp` and when not to. A good example of when to use `highp` is specular lighting calculations. They happen in view or world space often in large units for which `mediump` is not enough so you'd want that part only to be `highp` and rest `mediump` for speed (if you care). If you really want to support those older phones you need to check for them and use different shaders.

Comment: Worked on my app too. I can't imagine why mediup would look so crummy on my iPad. Does it drop to half-precision floats?

Comment: @wcochran that is my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

On mobile devices, WebGL implementations can be sensitive to things like non-base two texture dimensions, or can require texture wrapping behaviour to be explicitly set.

I noticed your [grass texture](https://jameswebsite.azurewebsites.net/grass.jpg) has dimensions of 590x590. Consider resizing your textures to the closes base two dimensions (ie in the case of your grass texture, 512x512)

Also, I would recommend you explicity set the `gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T` parameters on your texture object(s) to `gl.GL_REPEAT`, as this may be another cause for your textures only partially displaying on geometry.

You can set wrapping behaviour on a texture object in the following way:

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT);
```

Comment: I just set them to GL_REPEAT to no avail. But I really think you are on the right track here... It's got to be something like that since it partially shows the textures. I may try sizing everything to base two dimensions, but would rather another solution. Thanks though!

Comment: You're welcome - let me know how you get on with textures of base two dimension. Nice game by the way!

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping to make it longer soon.I tried a texture of base two dimension (512x512) but it didn't work. I have turned textures off and the problem still persists. I think it might be in the shader then...

Comment: Ok, are you able to update your question with the shader code, or create a codepen?

Comment: Updated and now solved! Thanks for the suggestion to update it.